# How to get rows in Eloquent ordered by having most specific relationships?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1, relationship

I have a project in Laravel 5.1 with three tables: articles, tags and a pivot table to save many-to-many relationships: article_tag table.
I need to get all articles related by tags to a specific article, assigning a major number or relevance to those articles that have major number of coincidences by tag. So, first ones would be those which are "more related". 
For example, if I require all articles with tag_id #1 and #2, and if article A have both tags but article B have only one coincidence, I want get both articles ordered in sequence: A, B.

I think I can do it with a mysql statement:

```
SELECT articles.*, count(*) as tags_count 
FROM article_tag, articles 
WHERE tag_id in (1,2) 
AND articles.id = article_tag.article_id 
GROUP BY article_id 
ORDER BY tags_count DESC
```

But I want to use Eloquent. How can I approach it?

Comment: Not a direct answer as it's not a Eloquent approach BUT you can run RAW SQL via the query builder. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#running-queries

Comment: @Petay87 Thanks but it is not what I am looking for. That is what I have right now and I want to change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the raw sql query is the one you need, something like this should work:

```
$articles = Article::select(DB::raw('articles.*'), DB::raw('count(*) as tags_count'))
    ->join('article_tag', 'article_tag.article_id', '=', 'articles.id')
    ->whereIn('tag_id', [1, 2])
    ->groupBy('article_id')
    ->orderBy('tags_count', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

You will need `use DB;` in the model/controller where this code will be used, or you can do `\DB::raw(..)` instead.